# Generating Mock data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mocking

When I am generating mock as well as defining order quantity depending on the weights.Then, i am passing weights into random.choices() and it somehow recognize which product has the particular weight but dont know how it recognizes that. Btw, second value in the dict values list corresponds to the weights.

```
import datetime as dt
import calendar
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import uuid

products = {'iPhone': [700, 10],
  'Google Phone': [600, 8],
  'Vareebadd Phone': [400, 3],
  '20in Monitor': [109.99,6],
  '34in Ultrawide Monitor': [379.99, 9],
  '27in 4K Gaming Monitor': [389.99,9],
  '27in FHD Monitor': [149.99, 11],
  'Flatscreen TV': [300, 7],
  'Macbook Pro Laptop': [1700, 7],
  'ThinkPad Laptop': [999.99, 6],
  'AA Batteries (4-pack)': [3.84, 30],
  'AAA Batteries (4-pack)': [2.99, 30],
  'USB-C Charging Cable': [11.95, 30],
  'Lightning Charging Cable': [14.95, 30],
  'Wired Headphones': [11.99, 26],
  'Bose SoundSport Headphones': [99.99, 19],
  'Apple Airpods Headphones': [150, 22],
  'LG Washing Machine': [600.00, 1],
  'LG Dryer': [600.00, 1]}


columns = ['Order ID', 'Product', 'Quantity Ordered', 'Price Each', 'Order Date', 'Purchase Address']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for i in range(999):
  products_list = [product for product in products]
  weights = [products[key][1] for key in products_list]
  
  product = random.choices(products_list, weights=weights)[0]
  price = products[product][0]


  df.loc[i] = [i, product, "NA" ,price, "NA", "NA"]

df.groupby("Product").count()
```

That is the result i got:

```
        Order ID    Quantity Ordered    Price Each  Order Date  Purchase Address
Product                 
20in Monitor    30  30  30  30  30
27in 4K Gaming Monitor  38  38  38  38  38
27in FHD Monitor    49  49  49  49  49
34in Ultrawide Monitor  35  35  35  35  35
AA Batteries (4-pack)   114 114 114 114 114
AAA Batteries (4-pack)  111 111 111 111 111
Apple Airpods Headphones    81  81  81  81  81
Bose SoundSport Headphones  68  68  68  68  68
Flatscreen TV   23  23  23  23  23
Google Phone    41  41  41  41  41
LG Dryer    5   5   5   5   5
LG Washing Machine  6   6   6   6   6
Lightning Charging Cable    110 110 110 110 110
Macbook Pro Laptop  24  24  24  24  24
ThinkPad Laptop 17  17  17  17  17
USB-C Charging Cable    116 116 116 116 116
Vareebadd Phone 7   7   7   7   7
Wired Headphones    90  90  90  90  90
iPhone  34  34  34  34  34
```

Comment: The code is missing `import` statements and `products_new` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry. now fixed)

Answer (score 0):

The list of products and weights are made with this code:

```
products_list = [product for product in products]
weights = [products[key][1] for key in products_list]
```

The first line produces a list of the keys in `products`.  It could be `list(products.keys())` or even `list(products)`.  The next line creates a list of the weights.  Iterating over a list yields the values in index-order, so the weight at `weights[i]` corresponds to the product at `product_list[i]`.  `random.choices()` uses the correspondence to know the weight of each item.  You can print `product_list` and `weights` to check:

```
w = max(len(p) for p in products)
print(f"{'i':>2}  {'product':{w}} {'wt':2}")
print(f"{'--'}  {'-'*w} {'--'}")
for i, (product, weight) in enumerate(zip(products_list, weights)):
    print(f"{i:2}: {product:.<{w}} {weight:2}")
```

Output:

```
 i  product                    wt
--  -------------------------- --
 0: iPhone.................... 10
 1: Google Phone..............  8
 2: Vareebadd Phone...........  3
 3: 20in Monitor..............  6
 4: 34in Ultrawide Monitor....  9
 5: 27in 4K Gaming Monitor....  9
 6: 27in FHD Monitor.......... 11
 7: Flatscreen TV.............  7
 8: Macbook Pro Laptop........  7
 9: ThinkPad Laptop...........  6
10: AA Batteries (4-pack)..... 30
11: AAA Batteries (4-pack).... 30
12: USB-C Charging Cable...... 30
13: Lightning Charging Cable.. 30
14: Wired Headphones.......... 26
15: Bose SoundSport Headphones 19
16: Apple Airpods Headphones.. 22
17: LG Washing Machine........  1
18: LG Dryer..................  1
```

Note: `product_list` and `weights` are the same every time through the loop.  Move those two lines before the loop to improve efficiency.  `random.choices()` takes a parameter `k`, that specifies how many choices to make, so you can remove the loop.  Revised code:

```
k = 999

product_list = list(products)
weights = [value[1] for value in products.values()]

random_products = random.choices(product_list, weights=weights, k=k)

price = [products[product][0] for product in random_products]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Order ID':list(range(k)),
                   'Product':random_products,
                   'Quantity Ordered':['NA']*k,
                   'Price Each':price,
                   'Order Date':['NA']*k,
                   'Purchase Address':['NA']*k,
                  })

df.groupby("Product").count()
```

#### alternate sampling method

First, convert `products` to a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(products,
                            orient="index",
                            columns=["price", "weight"])
```

Then use `DataFrame.sample()`:

```
number_of_samples = 10  # 999
sample = df.sample(number_of_samples, replace=True, weights="weight")
```

Convert the index to a column:

```
sample = sample.rename_axis('product').reset_index()
```

Lastly, get order counts:

```
sample.groupby('product').size()
```

Example output:

```
product
AA Batteries (4-pack)         3
AAA Batteries (4-pack)        1
Bose SoundSport Headphones    1
Flatscreen TV                 1
Google Phone                  1
Lightning Charging Cable      2
USB-C Charging Cable          1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is how choices function matches up the weights and the keys in the products_list which contains dict.keys() since i only pass keys not dictionary into the choices()?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation, super excited...